# GitHub action yaml formatting

Tags: yaml, formatting, github-actions

I'm trying to make GitHub CI

What's wrong with this formatting?
I have such a problem

> Invalid workflow file
> You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 8

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQo4e.png)

```js
name: Chart project CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  check-links:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [17.x]
    steps:
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Starting Node.js  ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: install modules
      - run: npm install
      - name: build project
      - run: npm build
      - name: unit test
      - run: npm test
```

Additional info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some indentation and syntax issue. Please find the correct code below. Here you can find a sample run. [Link](https://github.com/heyitsvajid/react-starter-kit/runs/7208178990?check_suite_focus=true)

```
name: Test CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  check-links:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [17.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Starting Node.js  ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: install modules
        run: npm install
      - name: build project
        run: npm build
      - name: unit test
        run: npm test
```